# LED on an Arduino

Tags: arduino

What would happen if I plugged an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) (3.1 V) or an LED (2.4 V) into the Arduino 3.5 V port? Will it damage the LED? Would I need a resistor? If so, what type?

Comment: In what way is this a programming question? It's strictly a hardware question, and is off-topic here.

Comment: try http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should really be concerned with is what kind of current will be passing through your LED. I'm guessing that your LED has a max operating current of about 20 mA and a normal current of 10 mA. Those 3.1 V or 2.4 V values are the forward voltage drop across your LED. If your Arduino port puts out 3.5 V and your LED drops 3.1 V then you still have 0.4 V that must be dropped across some sort of resistance. Since you would want to limit your current to about 10 mA through your LED you should set the resistance value that would be in series with the LED to a value of R = V/I or R = 0.4 V  / 0.01 A = 40 ohms.